# ICP algorithm on PCL returns "zero" transform matrix

Tags: point-cloud-library

I tried to use ICP algorithm on PCL with simple way, but it returns transform matrix which only has zero elements.

Environment:

- Windows10 + VS2019
- PCL 1.10.1 All-in-one

Code:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr src_ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
pcl::io::loadPCDFile("src.pcd", *src_ptr);

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr dst_ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
pcl::io::loadPCDFile("dst.pcd", *dst_ptr);
pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> icp;
icp.setMaximumIterations(1);

icp.setInputSource(src);
icp.setInputTarget(dst);

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> Final;
Eigen::Matrix4f guess;
icp.align(Final, guess);
std::cout << guess << std::endl;
```

Then, output is:

```
1.46937e-39   4.2039e-45  1.52256e-36  9.80909e-45
           0  5.51013e-40            0            0
 5.73972e-42  8.40779e-45  1.84388e-40  1.43901e-36
           0 -4.11424e-38            0  4.59163e-41
```

src.pcd is here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bFrrdPSCw4s4y2sFv_LvigtW_fNOFxfv/view?usp=sharing

dst.pcd is here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hQsv38P5J7MSc8VLs10g6Ue30sSTQPOm/view?usp=sharing

I appreciate if you give me any advise

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood the usage of align().
I thought the second argument "guess" is a transformation matrix to fit source point cloud to target, but it was for initial position of source.

Therefore, the correct usage is:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> Final;
Eigen::Matrix4f guess;
icp.align(Final);
guess = icp.getFinalTransformation();
std::cout << guess << std::endl;
```